# casting with Soap Web service return Map getting error

Tags: java, soap

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.xml.xml_soap.Map cannot be cast to java.util.Map
    at com.client.nsf.PatientNoShowAlert.displayAlert(PatientNoShowAlert.java:46)
    at com.main.InitExecuter$3.run(InitExecuter.java:84)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$4$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$4$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$3$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:674)
```

Comment: downvotes in 3, 2, 1...

Comment: Wow, yeah, you're going to need to tell us what you're trying to do and what you expect to happen. Also, if possible, you should add the relevant code where the error is being produced.